# Using two Thintecture Identity servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-replication, thinktecture-ident-server

Good day, I would just like to find out if I can achieve the following situation using the Thintecture Identity Server v2?

I want to implement a situation where I have two Identity servers running in two different locations, One locally on our premises, and another on the internet at our Host.

I would like the two servers to somehow be in sync, I do not know how, maybe replicate the database with sql replication.

Then each of my applications would have a default STS server and if it cannot access the default it will try the secondary one.

Is this some possible to achieve without redesigning the whoel identity server and the packages used on the end use applications?

The applications that will be authenticating will be either asp.net MVC or Asp.net web api or will make use of Single page Application using Javascript with calls to asp.net web api

With the replication:
 Which identity server database will need to be replicated?

Comment: Sounds more like an infrastructure problem than a code one - you need a network appliance that can route the traffic to the nearest server and fallback if it isn't available. Probably still need some form of replication. [Log shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx) perhaps?

Comment: I feel it would possibly be easier to do in code on the client side, that way I can configure each app to use the appropriate server based on where it is hosted. And not depend on any sort of networking configuration or setup

Comment: Possibly, but hard to detect when to failover when using a browser-based authentication flow. You'd need to determine if and when the page failed to load and then use the fallback. Feels like something that should be handled at the network level... For replication would imagine you'd need to replicate both configuration and user stores